# Google distance matrix api issue with zipcode with different formats

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I need to get drive times for a place to the nearest airports. There is a service which is already in place which gives me the address of the place as well as the address of nearest airports in the north america region. One airport has a 5 digit zipcode, one has the zipcode this format 83402 4906, other has a zipcode in this format(canada) A12 123

The distance matrix api is not accepting all other zipcode formats apart from the 5 digit one. If I remove the space its not working.

I need to get the drive times irrespective of the zipcode format

Comment: can you share the request which is causing the problem?